# JS cross-browser solution for replacing '$' character with double '$$' character

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, replace

I have tried the following:

```
var stringToBeReplaced = "$";
var result = stringToBeReplaced.replace("$", "$$$$");
```

It works in modern browsers and I get `"$$"` in `result`. But to my surprise, when I run it over IE8 or older, I get `"$$$$"` in `result`. Is it a browser bug? Is there a cross browser solution avoiding browser detection? Just vainilla js please, no frameworks.

Comment: That's really really not a duplicate of this question ! OP obviously already knows that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably works :

```
var result = stringToBeReplaced.replace(/(\$)/g, "$1$1");
```

but I must confess I have no IE to test.

Comment: Why are you capturing it?

Comment: @thefourtheye In order to use $1

Comment: Oh Silly me, I didnt see the replacement part. But, do you know why IE behaves that way?

Comment: It looks like it doesn't interpret the $ things when executing `replace` with a string as first parameter but I'm no IE expert and it might be a little more complicated, that's why I *also* preferred to use $1.

Comment: Alternatively `var result = stringToBeReplaced.replace(/\$/g,function(m){ return m+m });`

Answer (score 2):

You can try `replace` with `callback`:

```
'$'.replace('$', function($0) { return '$$'; });
"$$"
```

**PS:** I have tested it on Firefox, Chrome and IE8